Change focus to input field in dropdown in summernote after dropdown is shown
I'm working on a WYSIWYG editor with a set of predefined text blocks that can be inserted in the current text. To do this, I created a custom button with a dropdown menu that displays an input field. I want this input field to become focused when diplayed, but haven't figured out how to do this. I'm using summernote 0.8.18 and Boostrap 4.
This is what I came up with:
HTML
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#summernote').summernote({
      height: 500,
      focus: false,
      toolbar: [
        ['mybutton',['customText']],
        ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
        ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
        ['para', ['paragraph']],
        ['view', ['fullscreen', 'codeview', 'help']]
      ],
      buttons: {
        customText: customText
      },
      callbacks: {
        onInit: function(e) {
          $("#summernote").summernote("fullscreen.toggle");
        }
      }
    });
  });
</script>

JS
var customText = function (context) {
  var ui = $.summernote.ui;
  var button = ui.buttonGroup([
      ui.button({
          className: "dropdown-toggle",
          contents:
            '<span class="fa-solid fa-wand-magic-sparkles"></span> <span class="caret"></span>',
          tooltip: "Insert custom text",
          data: {
            toggle: "dropdown"
          },
          click: function() {
            $('.search-input').focus().select();
          }
      }),
      ui.dropdown({
          className: "note-dropdown-menu dropdown-menu",
          contents:
            '<div class="input-group">' +
            '<input type="text" class="form-control search-input">' +
            '<div class="input-group-append">' +
              '<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Insert</button>' +
            '</div></div>',
          callback: function ($dropdown) {
            $dropdown.find(".btn").click(function () {
              context.invoke("editor.insertText", "Custom text");
            });
          }
      })
  ]);
  return button.render();   // return button as jquery object
};

It displays the search field, but the user has to click in it to start typing.
